# If the input is a random permutation of integers 1 through n. The average case running time of (Deterministic) Quicksort is Θ(n^2). True of False?

Tags: performance, time-complexity, quicksort

I know that the worst case running time of a deterministic quicksort algorithm (quicksort where the pivot is specific, such as the first element of the array or last element of the array) is Θ(n^2) but is the average case runningtime also Θ(n^2)? I was thinking the average case runningtime would be Θ(nlogn) but I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like it might be homework..

Regardless, quicksort is O(n^2) worst case and Θ(nlogn) average case.